# Dependent variable labels in stargazer tables

Tags: r, stargazer

When passing a character vector to the `dep.var.labels` argument to `stargazer`, I expected the dependent variable labels to consist of this vector. But this only seems to happen when the models are of different types.

```
data(mtcars)
m0 <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data=mtcars)
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars)
m2 <- glm(cyl ~ disp, data=mtcars)

## Only shows the label 'foo' for both models.
stargazer(m0, m1, dep.var.labels=c('foo','bar'))

## shows 'foo' and 'bar' as labels.
stargazer(m0, m2, dep.var.labels=c('foo','bar'))
```

How can I get stargazer to show different dependent variable labels even when the models are of the same type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`stargazer` uses the same dependent variable because your dependent variables are the same, not because you are using the same kind of statistical model. You may be interested in using the `column.labels` argument:

```
data(mtcars)
m0 <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data=mtcars)
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars)
m2 <- glm(cyl ~ disp, data=mtcars)

## Only shows the label 'foo' for both models.
stargazer(m0, m1, column.labels=c('foo','bar'), type="text")

## shows 'foo' and 'bar' as labels.
stargazer(m0, m2, column.labels=c('foo','bar'), type="text")
```

Comment: Is there a way to include bars below the column labels? It would easily visualize the groups.